# Taylor expand $f(x,y)=\sqrt{1+x+y}$ around $(1,0).$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

According to my book:

> The Taylor expansion for a function of two
>   variables $f(x,y)$ around a stationary point $(a,b)$ has the
>   appearance $$f(a+h,a+k) =
> > f(a,b)-\frac{1}{2}(Ah^2+2Bhk+Ck^2)+(h^2+k^2)^{3/2}B(h,k), \quad (1)$$
>
> where $B(h,k)$ is a bounded function and $A=f''_{xx}(a,b), \
> > B=f''_{xy}(a,b), \ C=f''_{yy}(a,b)$.

Using this with $(a,b)=(1,0)$ I get

$$f(1,0) = \sqrt{1+1+0}=\sqrt{2}\\ f'_x=f'_y=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+x+y}} \\ f''_{x}=f''_{xy}=f''_{yy}=-\frac{1}{4(1+x+y)^{3/2}}$$

$$\implies A=B=C = -\frac{1}{4(1+1+0)^{3/2}}=-\frac{1}{8\sqrt{2}}.$$

Plugging it into (1) gives

\begin{array}{lcl}
f(1+h,0+k) & = & \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}}(h^2+2hk+k^2) + (h^2+k^2)^{3/2}B(h,k) \\
& = & \sqrt{2}-\frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}}(h+k)^2 + (h^2+k^2)^{3/2}B(h,k) \\
\end{array}

---

**Correct answer:** $$\sqrt{2}+\color{green}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}(h+k)}-\frac{1}{16\sqrt{2}}(h+k)^2 + (h^2+k^2)^{3/2}B(h,k)$$

Where did the green term come from?

Comment: When did taylorexpand become a verb? :-(

Comment: Seems it became a verb a minute a go :P. I edited, I hope the edit pleases you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Taylor expansion around a *stationary point* $(a,b)$ looks as given in  text underlined in skin tone. Such a point is characterized by $f_x(a,b)=f_y(a,b)=0$; hence in this case there are no linear terms in the Taylor expansion. But the point $(1,0)$ is not a stationary point of *your* $f$ since
$$f_x(x,y)=f_y(x,y)={1\over 2\sqrt{1+x+y}}\ ,$$
which is $={1\over2\sqrt{2}}\ne0$ at $(1,0)$ (you have a wrong sign here). This value produces the linear term
$${1\over2\sqrt{2}}(h+k)$$
 in the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $(1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

In a single variable Taylor expansion

$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + \frac 12 f''(a)(x-a)^2$

In the multivariate expansion you are doing the same thing.

$f(x, y) = f(a,b) + f_x(a,b) (x-a) + f_y(a,b)(y-b) + \cdots$

Ah, I see the problem $(1,0)$ is not a stationary point.